# Testing GitHub SSH connection - Error: Permission denied (publickey), how to fix?

Tags: git, github, ssh, git-bash

I have followed [the GitHub Docs instructions](https://docs.github.com/en/github/authenticating-to-github/connecting-to-github-with-ssh) on how to create and add an SSH key to the letter, from generating a new key to adding it to my GitHub account.

I am using Git Bash to execute this on Win10. I have generated an RSA keypair successfully, it has been added to the ssh-agent, I have copy pasted the public key into my GitHub account without any extra spaces etc.

When I reach the 'Testing your SSH connection' phase, the command `ssh -T git@github.com` returns `git@github.com: Permission denied (publickey).`

I have read through every troubleshooting suggestion on [this page](https://docs.github.com/en/github/authenticating-to-github/error-permission-denied-publickey) and none of these fixes seem to resolve the problem.

My output from the command `ssh -i ~/.ssh/id_rsa -vT git@github.com` is as follows:

```
OpenSSH_8.4p1, OpenSSL 1.1.1i  8 Dec 2020
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: Connecting to github.com [140.82.121.3] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: identity file /c/Users/USER/.ssh/id_rsa type 0
debug1: identity file /c/Users/USER/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_8.4
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version babeld-c34a939f
debug1: no match: babeld-c34a939f
debug1: Authenticating to github.com:22 as 'git'
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug1: kex: algorithm: curve25519-sha256
debug1: kex: host key algorithm: rsa-sha2-512
debug1: kex: server->client cipher: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com MAC: <implicit> compression: none
debug1: kex: client->server cipher: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com MAC: <implicit> compression: none
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_REPLY
debug1: Server host key: ssh-rsa SHA256:nThbg6kXUpJWGl7E1IGOCspRomTxdCARLviKw6E5SY8
debug1: Host 'github.com' is known and matches the RSA host key.
debug1: Found key in /c/Users/USER/.ssh/known_hosts:1
debug1: rekey out after 134217728 blocks
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug1: rekey in after 134217728 blocks
debug1: Will attempt key: /c/Users/USER/.ssh/id_rsa RSA SHA256:sfCBsdTYd4G3HCltcpNdV68RksreyBB8vruHjzLHkxM explicit agent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_EXT_INFO received
debug1: kex_input_ext_info: server-sig-algs=<ssh-ed25519-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256-cert-v01@openssh.com,rsa-sha2-512-cert-v01@openssh.com,rsa-sha2-256-cert-v01@openssh.com,ssh-rsa-cert-v01@openssh.com,ssh-dss-cert-v01@openssh.com,ssh-ed25519,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,rsa-sha2-512,rsa-sha2-256,ssh-rsa,ssh-dss>
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Offering public key: /c/Users/USER/.ssh/id_rsa RSA SHA256:sfCBsdTYd4G3HCltcpNdV68RksreyBB8vruHjzLHkxM explicit agent
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey
debug1: No more authentication methods to try.
git@github.com: Permission denied (publickey).
```

Replacing the path after `-i` in the `ssh` command with `~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub` yields the same results.

Could someone please help me trace what is going wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

Solved - I was following instructions for a regular GitHub.com SSH connection, while trying to connect to a GitHub enterprise server.

Testing with the correct command - `ssh -T git@github.[ENTERPRISE ADDRESS]` gives a connection as expected.

For reference, I have been alerted that in the dropdown top right of GitHub docs, you can select the article version; for GitHub.com, GitHub AE or Enterprise Server versions.